# Filtering data in R

Tags: r, filtering

I have a CSV of file of data that I can load in R using `read.csv()`

Some of the data is missing, so I want to reduce the data frame down to set that consists entirely of non-missing data, i.e. if a `NULL` appears anywhere, I want to exclude that column and row from the filtered data set.

I know I can probably do this fairly simply with the inbuilt R vector operations, but I am not quite sure how to do this exactly?

To make my question a little more concrete, here is a quick sample of the data so you can see what I want to do.

```
DocID       Anno1    Anno7  Anno8
1           7        NULL   8
2           8        NULL   3
44          10       2      3
45          6        6      6
46          1        3      4
49          3        8      5
62          4        NULL   9
63          2        NULL   4
67          11       NULL   3
91          NULL     9      7
92          NULL     7      5
93          NULL     8      8
```

So given this input, I need some code that will reduce the output to this.

```
DocID       Anno8
44          3
45          6
46          4
49          5
```

As `Anno8` is the only column with non-NULL data, and there are only four rows with non-NULL data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `x` is your `data.frame` (or `matrix`) then

```
x[ ,apply(x, 2, function(z) !any(is.na(z)))]
```

Since your example uses `NULL`, `is.na(·)` will be replaced by `is.null(·)`

Alternatively you can look at `subset(·)`.

Comment: Thanks @rguha, this is useful. How would this work if I wanted to get rid, in a specific column of the csv, of any value that is less than, say, 5?

Comment: @Rodolphe to get rid of any values in `sales` column where its lesser than 5: `data[data$sales >= 5, ]` is more straightforward

Answer (score 20):

You can drop any row containing a missing using na.omit(), however that's not what you want.  Moreover, the currently accepted answer is wrong.  It gives you complete columns, but does not drop the rows that have one or more missing values, which is what was asked for.  The correct answer can be obtained as:

```
> a <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(NA,1), c=c(3,4))
> a
  a  b c
1 1 NA 3
2 2  1 4
> na.omit(a)[,colSums(is.na(a))==0]
  a c
2 2 4
```

To see that the above answer is wrong:

```
> a[ ,apply(a, 2, function(z) !any(is.na(z)))]
  a c
1 1 3
2 2 4
```

Row 1 should be dropped because of the NA in column 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,0,1),b=c(NA,1,NA,1), c=c(3,4,5,1))

na.omit(a)
  a b c
2 2 1 4
4 1 1 1

a[rowSums(is.na(a))==0,]
  a b c
2 2 1 4
4 1 1 1

a[complete.cases(a),]
  a b c
2 2 1 4
4 1 1 1
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  This will always return only one row

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do it using `sqldf` library, if `x` is your dataframe:

```
library(sqldf)
result <- sqldf("SELECT DocID, Anno8 FROM x
                 WHERE Anno1 IS NOT NULL AND Anno7 IS NOT NULL")
```